# Script to find apps with "not responding" status, kill and restart the app in Windows XP

Tags: windows, batch-file

I tried:

```
taskkill /f /fi "status eq not responding"
```

This is not working. Even with an application with *not responding* status, I have this message:

> No tasks running with the specified criteria.

*not responding* status appears on **Applications** tab of Windows **Task Manager** for the application.

Comment: Could you please show us the OUTPUT of TASKLIST and then TASKKILL so we can see what is happening.  Thanks

Comment: @Snowman You better spend time on finding out why one of your applications become regularly not responsive and fix that instead of developing a batch file to __kill__ this application and start it again. Killing an application is never good and should never been done regularly on an application.

Comment: @ Mofi: It is many reasons. It's complicated. Developer abandoned the project.Could be some updates on Windows XP ...even necessary applications are incompatible with this program ... sometimes, when TeamViewer file transfer blocking one file... Didn't  lock frequently
 but when it does It just have to be restarted. But how do I know it blocked?   
############
@Squashman. The tasklist is the tasklist from "processes" tab. Not from Applications tab, where appear with "not responding" status. 
I remember when I made some tested with other app. In windows 7 it works but in xp didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I tried on Windows XP SP3 x86 the command:

```
tasklist /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"
```

And the output was:

> INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.

Next I tried the opposite:

```
tasklist /fi "STATUS eq RUNNING"
```

And the output was the same as above.

Then I searched in world wide web for web pages about **tasklist** with **filter** on **status** on **Windows XP** and found lots of pages all reporting the same as my own tests returned:

**Filtering on status is not working on Windows XP.**

This is obviously a bug of [tasklist](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tasklist.mspx) and [taskkill](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx) on Windows XP.

The newer [tasklist](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730909.aspx) documentation of Microsoft for Windows Server 2000 and later as well as the referenced documentation above for Windows XP contain both two **tasklist** examples with the filter option `/fi "STATUS eq running"` on command line. But both output on Windows XP just:

> INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.

Removing `/fi "STATUS eq running"` from each example and run **tasklist** with the remaining parameter results in expected output.

So I thought about working around this bug of **tasklist** and **taskkill** on my **German Windows XP** by using

```
tasklist /v /fi "USERNAME ne NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM" /fi "USERNAME ne NT-AUTORITÄT\NETZWERKDIENST"
```

and filter the output for task with **not responding** in output.

But this also does not work. I let a GUI application run into an endless loop and therefore showing the status **Not Responding** (German: Keine Rückmeldung) on tab **Applications** in **Windows Task Manager**. But in output of command above the GUI application was still listed with status **Running** (German: Wird ausgeführt).

It looks like it is really impossible on Windows XP using **tasklist** or **taskkill** to find and kill applications with status **not responding** in Windows Task Manager from command line.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe someone with more skills can give me some advice how could I do this. With sysinternals tools ? With other app... Thanks Mofi !

Comment: "I let a GUI application run into an endless loop and therefore showing the status Not Responding" 
Mofi, can you help me with this app ?
That will provide me a start point to find a way.

Comment: I used text editor UltraEdit (for XP), wrote into a new file `UltraEdit.newFile(); while (UltraEdit.activeDocument.isEof());`, saved the file as `EndlessLoop.js` and clicked in menu __Scripting__ on __Run Active Script__. This results in an endless running script and therefore UltraEdit becomes not responsive as it can be seen in Windows Task Manager as well as when clicking on X symbol of UE main window. But script execution can be exited with a click on button __Cancel__ displayed in a small dialog window since starting the script making UltraEdit responsive again.

Comment: [Sysinternals PsList](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pslist) does not return a process status information at least on Windows XP according to my tests. Also `wmic process list status` shows nothing in column `Status` for all processes on Windows XP. When the process becomes not responsive because of running in an endless loop, checking cpu usage of the process could be a solution. But this is of no help if application becomes not responsive because of waiting for something which never occurs like a bad coded thread management (semaphore or mutex issue).